# Append lines of data to a Pandas Dataframe that is not associated with the existing dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to go about adding lines of text to an existing Pandas Dataframe?

I have saved a pandas dataframe via this command:

```
predictionsdf = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['File_name', 'Actual_class', 'pred_class', 'Boom'])
```

The saved data looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to add lines of text like this:

```
 Total # of Boom detection =  1 from 100 files 
 Percentage of Boom detection from plastic bag pop =  1.0 % 
 Time:  0.43 mins
```

At the bottom of the dataframe data.

Can you tell me how to go about appending these lines to the bottom of the dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: @CodeDifferent, do I have to change the Lines of text to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what you are trying to do here, but with the following toy dataframe and lines of text:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 100)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "File_name": [
            "15FT_LabCurtain_S9_pt5GAL_TCL.wav",
            "15FT_LabCurtain_S9_pt6GAL_TCL.wav",
            "15FT_LabCurtain_S9_pt7GAL_TCL.wav",
        ],
        "Actual_class": ["plastic_bag", "plastic_bag", "plastic_bag"],
        "pred_class": ["plastic_bag", "plastic_bag", "plastic_bag"],
        "Boom": [0, 0, 1],
    }
)

lines = (
    "Total # of Boom detection =  1 from 100 files",
    "Percentage of Boom detection from plastic bag pop =  1.0 %",
    "Time:  0.43 mins",
)
```

You could try this:

```py
for line in lines:
    df.loc[df.shape[0] + 1, "File_name"] = line
df = df.fillna("")

print(df)
# Output
                                                    File_name Actual_class   pred_class Boom
0                           15FT_LabCurtain_S9_pt5GAL_TCL.wav  plastic_bag  plastic_bag  0.0
1                           15FT_LabCurtain_S9_pt6GAL_TCL.wav  plastic_bag  plastic_bag  0.0
2                           15FT_LabCurtain_S9_pt7GAL_TCL.wav  plastic_bag  plastic_bag  1.0
4               Total # of Boom detection =  1 from 100 files
5  Percentage of Boom detection from plastic bag pop =  1.0 %
6                                            Time:  0.43 mins
```